# how to insert vb macro into another workbook programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking around the internet for an answer but they all insert the code from python or batch but i would like to make a vb macro that creates a macro inside of an excel workbook.

Comment: Start [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx), but I can't see how this is a good idea.

Comment: it keeps saying "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject

Comment: Read the whole thing, including the part at the very beginning about adding a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3`